# How to remove a specific element when generating xml using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB to create xml .

It seems that an xml element is created with the current variable name, but the upper list object does not want to be created as an xml element.

However, the parent list object is created with a variable name, how to remove the corresponding element?

Currently my source code is as below.

```
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="POCD_MT000040.Entry", propOrder={"ant123"})
public class POCDMT000040Entry
{
    protected List<DataTest> ant123;

    public List<DataTest> getAnt123() {
    return ant123;
}

public void setAnt123(List<DataTest> ant123) {
    this.ant123 = ant123;
}
}



@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="DataTest", propOrder={"datatitle", "data"})
public class DataTest
{
   protected ST datatitle;
   protected Data data;

     public ST getDatatitle() {
    return datatitle;
}

public void setDatatitle(ST datatitle) {
    this.datatitle = datatitle;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

`I want xml like below.`

```
<entry>
  <datatitle>1</datatitle>
  <data>1</data>
  <datatitle>2</datatitle>
  <data>2</data>
  <datatitle>3</datatitle>
  <data>3</data>
</entry>
```

`But the xml is being generated like this.`

```
<entry>
 <ant123>
  <datatitle>1</datatitle>
  <data>1</data>
 </ant123>
 <ant123>
  <datatitle>2</datatitle>
  <data>2</data>
 </ant123>
 <ant123>
  <datatitle>3</datatitle>
  <data>3</data>
 </ant123>
</entry>
```

I want to remove the ant123 element.
Can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: What is `ST datatitle` and `Data data;` in your code? Could you share it?

Comment: I put my answer below. Please confirm.

Comment: I can see in your code classes 'ED' and 'ANY' which I don't know. Can you try to change your code so that as few components are needed and the code compiles?
+ What function do you use for Marshalling? Can you show an example?
BR.

Comment: I solved this problem using that annotation.
Change "List<DataTest> ant123" => "List<Object> titleOrData"

@XmlElements({@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name="data", type=Data.class), @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(name="datatitle", type=ST.class)})
protected List<Object> titleOrData;

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The items of my ST and Data are as below.

I have described datatitle and data in the description, but the attribute has different values.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ST", propOrder={"type"})
@XmlSeeAlso({ SC.class, ADXP.class, ENXP.class})
public class ST extends ED {

@XmlAttribute(name = "type")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
protected String type;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Data", propOrder={"type","reference","text"})
@XmlSeeAlso({ SC.class, ADXP.class, ENXP.class})
public class Data extends ANY {


protected POCDMT000040Reference reference;

@XmlAttribute(name = "type")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
protected String type;

protected ST text;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}



public POCDMT000040Reference getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(POCDMT000040Reference reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public ST getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(ST text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

**I want xml like below.**

```
<entry>
    <datatitle mediaType="">1</datatitle>
    <data type="TEXT">
        <text>1</text>
    </data>
    <datatitle mediaType="">2</datatitle>
    <data type="TEXT">
        <text>2</text>
    </data>
</entry>
```

**But the xml is being generated like this..**

```
<entry>
 <any123>
    <datatitle mediaType="">1</datatitle>
    <data type="TEXT">
        <text>1</text>
    </data>
 </any123>
 <any123>
    <datatitle mediaType="">2</datatitle>
    <data type="TEXT">
        <text>2</text>
    </data>
 </any123>
</entry>
```